# Removing object from images using grayscale mask python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, opencv

i have a small problem with my python script

i have an image like this one:

[image: street with people]

and I created a grayscale mask of the image highlighting the people in black and everything else in white:

[image: grayscale mask]

my goal would be to transform the original image into a png, and using the mask cut out the people, leaving a transparent "hole" in place of each person
This is my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

original_image = cv2.imread('ok/114_0175.jpg')
mask = cv2.imread('masks/114_0175.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

transparent_image = cv2.bitwise_and(original_image, original_image, mask=mask)

cv2.imwrite('paesaggio_con_persone_trasparenti.png', transparent_image)
```

the problem is that with this code the people are only replaced by the black of the mask, and they are not made transparent, how could I solve this problem?

this is the result of the code:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build a 4-channel array and `imwrite()` that instead. Put the alpha values in the fourth channel.

Do make sure to erase the color channels on those people. Just setting alpha to 0 does not erase the color data, just hides it.

```
(h, w) = original_image.shape

alpha_channel = np.full((h, w), 255, dtype=np.uint8)

...

with_alpha_channel = np.dstack([transparent_image, alpha_channel])
```

You can also build a 4-channel array with OpenCV: `cv.cvtColor(..., cv.COLOR_BGR2BGRA)`

Comment: edited with ```alpha_channel = np.where(mask > 0, 255, 0).astype(np.uint8)``` but now it works, thank you!